# Issues on bundling (angular2 + webpack bundling)

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification, typescript-typings

Here is my package.json. I added the dependencies for webpack.I had a confusion whether my denpendencies and scripts correct?. Because, when i do npm start, it starts bundling and started the angular2 project on browser, there i had an issue that **Cannot get app.bundle.js**, i have provided the index.html,webpack.config.js below,..

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "ng2-spin-kit": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "^1.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.1",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

> "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config webpack.config.js
>   --progress"

And the webpack.config.js file is

```js
var webpack = require('webpack'),
  glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    'myPages': glob.sync('./src/**/*.js'), // here including js files from src folder
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    library: "node_modules",
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: 'node-loader'
      },
      // Javascript: js, jsx
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      // CSS: scss, css

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style!css"
      },
      // HTML: htm, html
      {
        test: /\.html?$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
    })
  ]
};
```

The webpack.config.js gives the bundled output file named 'dist/app.bundle.js'(inside the dist folder), but i had an issue in inserting the app.bundle.js file into the html page, my index.html is

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular_E&O</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <base href="/E&O">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
         <script src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
    <mainapp>content loading..</mainapp>
</body>

</html>
```

> index.html is invoked

```js
<script src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

> in this script line i got error, that it could not get
>   app.bundle.js, even i checked the path was also right

As i am begginer to the webpack bundling, please help me out,..

Answer (score 0):

please add the bundled js file after the root tag
like this

```
<mainapp>content loading..</mainapp>
<script src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```